# How would this RewriteRule look?

Tags: mod-rewrite

How would I rewrite:

```
character.php?name=Agame
```

to:

```
character/Agame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rewrite requests to `/character/…` internally to `/character.php?name=…`, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^character/([^/]+)$ character.php?name=$1 [L]
```

But if you really want to redirect requests to `/character.php?name=…` to `/character/…`, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&+)*name=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^character\.php$ /character/%2? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks alot, my urls are gonna be so sexy now!